# How do I choose the locator for the dropdown list in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

this is the code where the value `d3395be8-doctype` changes everytime the page reload. I am really having trouble automating this scenario.

```
<select id="d3395be8-doctype" style="height:24px;width:100%;" name="d3395be8-doctype" changeevent="true
```

this is the command i use. it always return errors:

```
XPath: //*[ends-with(@id, 'doctype')]
```

Comment: [error] Element xpath://select[ends-with(@id, '-doctype')]/@id not found

Comment: @alecxe above is the error

Comment: `//*[ends-with(@id, 'doctype')]` looked ok to me, should work. There is probably something else going on. Not enough details to help.

Comment: Please Provide Compete HTML code snippet of the Drop-down box and highlight the option which is changing dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be because the `ends-with` function is part of xpath 2.0 but your browser might only support 1.0. As a test you can try `//*contains(@id, '-doctype')` If that works, then it's highly probably that this is your issue. If you want to get more precise with the locator you can roll your own version of `ends-with` using the `string-length` and `substring` functions.